# Tax on US income for work days spent in India

Tags: usa, working-visas, taxes, india, tax-treaties

I moved to US in May 2019 on a work visa. I am a resident in US and non-resident in India for the respective tax periods.

I spent 3 weeks working in India in Dec 2019. My salary was still generated in the US. Would I need to pay taxes in India on the income for these 3 weeks?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to Indian tax laws you are required to pay taxes on salary you earned while working in India. However you can claim a tax credit on the amount when you file your USA taxes. This assumes you are an Indian citizen.

Comment: This would be a more persuasive answer if it included the source(s) for your statement. Sources might include citation(s) to Indian tax law, or responsible commentary, or even your own personal experience in dealing with the Indian tax authorities.

Comment: This is what my CPA in the US had me do for my income when I filed my returns. I don’t know the exact rule.

Comment: Very good. That a tax professional advised you to do this gives some weight to your answer.